# single istanbul command for multiple scripts (or combined coverage reports)

Tags: javascript, testing, code-coverage, istanbul

I would like to run several tests in their own process and combine the istanbul reports somehow.

For example, two implementations:

```
//sut1.js
'use strict'
module.exports = function() {
  return 42
}
```

and

```
//sut2.js
'use strict'
module.exports = function() {
  return '42'
}
```

and two tests:

```
//test1.js
'use strict'
const expect = require('chai').expect
const sut1 = require('./sut1.js')
expect(sut1()).to.equal(42)
expect(sut1()).not.to.equal('42')
console.log('looks good')
```

and:

```
//test2.js
'use strict'
const expect = require('chai').expect
const sut2 = require('./sut2.js')

describe('our other function', function() {
  it('should give you a string', function() {
    expect(sut2()).to.equal('42')
  })

  it('should not give a a number', function () {
    expect(sut2()).not.to.equal(42)
  })
})
```

I can get a coverage report for either one like this:

```
istanbul cover --print both test1.js
istanbul cover --print both -- node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test2.js
```

What is the easiest way to get a combined coverage report?  Is there a one liner that will also output it?

With mocha or jasmine, you can just pass in multiple files, but here I want to actually run different scripts.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody is interested, answer is:

- don't use istanbul; use nyc - so that you can pass executables to it
  instead of just javascript files
- put the two tests in a bash file
  together and run that with istanbul

...

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# test.sh

set -e

node test1.js
node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test2.js
```

and then go like this

```
nyc ./test.sh
```

and you will see the combined test output:

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 sut1.js  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 sut2.js  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 test1.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 test2.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

you can also do it in package.json's scripts like this:

```
"_test": "node test1.js && mocha test2.js",
"test": "nyc npm run _test",
```

Answer (score 2):

Since my last answer, I have discovered how to actually combine the reports, if it is not possible to combine all the tests into a single call.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# test.sh

set -e

COMBINED_OUTPUT=nyc_output

rm -rf $COMBINED_OUTPUT
mkdir $COMBINED_OUTPUT
node_modules/.bin/nyc -s node test1.js # leave off -s if you want to see partial results
cp .nyc_output/* $COMBINED_OUTPUT
node_modules/.bin/nyc -s node_modules/.bin/mocha test2.js
cp .nyc_output/* $COMBINED_OUTPUT
node_modules/.bin/nyc report -t $COMBINED_OUTPUT
```

Each call to `nyc` will clear the directory `.nyc_output`.  However, if you copy all of the output after each operation to another folder, which I have called `nyc_output`, as each file is created with a unique name, you can get `nyc` to generate a report for you at the end using all of the coverage files.  If you `nyc -s`, it will not print the coverage table for that nyc operation.

the result is the same as the other answer

```
$ ./test.sh 
looks good


  our other function
    ✓ should give you a string
    ✓ should not give a a number


  2 passing (7ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 sut1.js  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 sut2.js  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 test1.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 test2.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```